# Why is mongoDB aggregation $count method gives an object of AggregationCursor as result using node.js and promise?

Tags: mongodb, promise, aggregation-framework

I am trying to get  count of an array in a document by using `Mongodb aggregation` `$count` operator.
I am using `node.js` and `promise` for this. Here is my code:

```
getDaysPresent:(id)=>{
return new Promise(async(resolve,reject)=>{
 let days=await db.get().collection(collection.'student_collection').aggregate([
        {
            $match:{_id:ObjectId(id)}
        },{
            $unwind:"$attendance"
        },{
            $count:"attendance"
        }
    ])
    resolve(days)   
})
```

}

When I try this Mongo Db code in Robo3T it gives the key and value object properly. But when code
executed the console of days gives a AggregationCursor objects with the below details:

```
 AggregationCursor {
     _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: true,
highWaterMark: 16,
buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
length: 0,
pipes: null,
pipesCount: 0,
flowing: null,
ended: false,
endEmitted: false,
reading: false,
sync: true,
needReadable: false,
emittedReadable: false,
readableListening: false,
resumeScheduled: false,
emitClose: true,
autoDestroy: false,
destroyed: false,
defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
awaitDrainWriters: null,
multiAwaitDrain: false,
readingMore: false,
decoder: null,
encoding: null,
[Symbol(kPaused)]: null
 },
 readable: true,
   _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
   _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
 operation: AggregateOperation {
options: { readPreference: [ReadPreference] },
ns: MongoDBNamespace { db: 'classroom', collection: '$cmd' },
readPreference: ReadPreference {
  mode: 'primary',
  tags: undefined,
  hedge: undefined
},
readConcern: undefined,
writeConcern: undefined,
explain: false,
fullResponse: true,
target: 'student',
pipeline: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
hasWriteStage: false,
cursorState: {
  cursorId: null,
  cmd: {},
  documents: [],
  cursorIndex: 0,
  dead: false,
  killed: false,
  init: false,
  notified: false,
  limit: 0,
  skip: 0,
  batchSize: 1000,
  currentLimit: 0,
  transforms: undefined,
  raw: undefined,
  reconnect: true
}
 },
 pool: null,
 server: null,
 disconnectHandler: undefined,
 bson: undefined,
 ns: 'classroom.$cmd',
 namespace: MongoDBNamespace { db: 'classroom', collection: '$cmd' },
cmd: {},
options: {
 readPreference: ReadPreference {
  mode: 'primary',
  tags: undefined,
  hedge: undefined
}
 },
  topology: Server {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
  commandStarted: [Function],
  commandSucceeded: [Function],
  commandFailed: [Function],
  serverOpening: [Function],
  serverClosed: [Function],
  serverDescriptionChanged: [Function],
  serverHeartbeatStarted: [Function],
  serverHeartbeatSucceeded: [Function],
  serverHeartbeatFailed: [Function],
  topologyOpening: [Function],
  topologyClosed: [Function],
  topologyDescriptionChanged: [Function],
  joined: [Function],
  left: [Function],
  ping: [Function],
  ha: [Function],
  connectionPoolCreated: [Function],
  connectionPoolClosed: [Function],
  connectionCreated: [Function],
  connectionReady: [Function],
  connectionClosed: [Function],
  connectionCheckOutStarted: [Function],
  connectionCheckOutFailed: [Function],
  connectionCheckedOut: [Function],
  connectionCheckedIn: [Function],
  connectionPoolCleared: [Function],
  authenticated: [Function],
  error: [Array],
  timeout: [Array],
  close: [Array],
  parseError: [Array],
  open: [Array],
  fullsetup: [Array],
  all: [Array],
  reconnect: [Array]
  },
  _eventsCount: 35,
  _maxListeners: Infinity,
  s: {
  coreTopology: [Server],
  sCapabilities: [ServerCapabilities],
  clonedOptions: [Object],
  reconnect: true,
  emitError: true,
  poolSize: 5,
  storeOptions: [Object],
  store: [Store],
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 27017,
  options: [Object],
  sessionPool: [ServerSessionPool],
  sessions: Set {},
  promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise]
   },
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
 },
cursorState: {
cursorId: null,
cmd: {},
documents: [],
cursorIndex: 0,
dead: false,
killed: false,
init: false,
notified: false,
limit: 0,
skip: 0,
batchSize: 1000,
currentLimit: 0,
transforms: undefined,
raw: undefined,
reconnect: true
 },
 logger: Logger { className: 'Cursor' },
 s: {
numberOfRetries: 5,
tailableRetryInterval: 500,
currentNumberOfRetries: 5,
state: 0,
promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
explicitlyIgnoreSession: false
  },
 [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  }
```

My sample document as follow:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5fd6fa3b4150e552f0b75935"),
"Name" : "Bobby",
"Gender" : "Male",
"RollNo" : "1",
"attendance" : [ 
    "2/1/2021", 
    "3/1/2021", 
    "4/1/2021"
   ]
 }
```

IF you guys know about this please let me know. And by the by this is my first question in stackoverflow so please give me suggestions to improve this question. Thank you

Comment: Do you mind adding an example document from your collection? It does not need to be real data. It simply may help others in the community to be helpful.

Comment: You need to collect the aggregation results to a list, assuming there are few enough for this to make sense to do. Check mode.js client documentation.

Comment: {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5fd6fa3b4150e552f0b75935"),
       "Name" : "Bobby",
       "Gender" : "Male",
    "attendance" : [ 
        "2/1/2021", 
        "3/1/2021", 
        "4/1/2021"
    ]
}

Comment: If you do `console.log(days)` just before `resolve(days)` whats the result? Also I think the `$match` stage in your query should be `$match:{_id:ObjectId(id)}`

Comment: the result be same for `console.log(days)` before `resolve(days)`. ok, now `$match:{_id:ObjectId(id)}` but still same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the `$count` properly, when I add [toArray()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/) to the end of aggregation method. The count object will be in an array.

```
 getPresentDays:(id)=>{
  return new Promise(async(resolve,reject)=>{
   var days=await db.get().collection(collection.STUDENT_COLLECTION).aggregate([
        {
            $match:{_id:ObjectId(id)}
        },{
            $unwind:"$attendance"
        },{
            $count:"attendance"
        }
    ]).toArray()
    resolve(days[0].attendance)   
})
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You could use `$size` operator to compute the length of an array field in the document. Please modify to suit the programming language and driver.

```
db.user.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      length: {
        $size: "$attendance"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/UbQh1feZaF0

Comment: Yes, this code also gives the count , but when promise is applied as my above code , I got the same aggregationCursor as out